# Retrieve content from specified list of S3 directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

Is there a way to retrieve list of all files from specified list of directories at specific `S3 bucket` by invoking cloud API only once?

For example, lets say that I have following structure at my `S3` cloud service:

```
A/
 AA/
   XXX/

B/
 BB/
   /EMPTY

C/
 /EMPTY

D/
 DD/
   XXX/
```

And that I also have list of directories from which I wish to retrieve content:

```
Requested Paths: {
    "A/AA/XXX",
    "B/BB/XXX",
    "C/CC/XXX",
    "D/DD/XXX"
}
```

I would like to create a map with key/value pairs where key is represented by specific directory path, and value is represented by its content. If path does not exist then key/value pair should not exist ether. Something like this:

```
Map {
   "A/AA/XXX" : Content
   "D/DD/XXX" : Content
}
```

Note that there are no keys that correspond to `B/BB/XXX` and `C/CC/XXX` since `XXX` is not part of `B/BB/`/path and `CC/XXX` is not part of `C/`  path ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a single call, no - particularly if you have enough objects to trigger paginated results. [`ListObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/api/service.s3.S3.html#service.s3.S3.ListObjects) takes a [`ListObjectsInput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/api/service.s3.ListObjectsInput.html) where `Prefix` is a single string, not a slice/array.

Comment: Thank you for your help!